# Jenkins - Which timestamp in build.xml correlates to config spec time rule?

Tags: xml, jenkins, timestamp, clearcase

I have a Jenkins set-up that POLLs ClearCase for changes. When changes are seen it modifies the config spec of the view with a timestamp rule. I'm curious where I can get that timestamp from build.xml of the job run.

Inside ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs//builds//build.xml I see a few items referencing time.

```
<buildTime>2017-09-29 20:12:13.647 UTC</buildTime>
<timestamp>1506715933647</timestamp>
<startTime>1506715933650</startTime>
```

Which one correlates to the timestamp being used in the config spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one correlates to the timestamp being used in the config spec?

For that, one would need to look at the config spec.
But assuming the config spec is using the date in the `buildTime` element, then `timestamp` (1506715933647) is the epoch time which matches `2017-09-29 20:12:13.647 UTC`.

In older Jenkins, [`BUILD_ID` used to include the timestamp](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project).
Now, [plugins need to set the `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` variable themselves](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26626).